# Clausula IN en iBatis/Mybatis

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, mybatis

Estoy en un proyecto en el que las consultas se hacen con ibatis, y estoy teniendo muchos problemas a la hora de pasarle una lista de string a la query.

A la query le paso un `hashMap` con 3 valores:

```
HashMap datos = new HashMap();
datos.put("idPlataforma", idPlataforma);
datos.put("idDispositivo", idDispositivo);
datos.put("listadoEESS", listadoEESS);
```

`idPlataforma` e `idDispostivio` son String, y `listadoEESS` es un listado de String.

Ahora bien, cuando llamo a la query la estoy haciendo así (solo pongo la parte de la lista de String ya que los otros dos van bien)

```
<isNotNull property="listadoEESS">
    AND ac.cod_accion = es.cod_accion
    AND es.n_concn in
    <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
        #listadoEESS[]#
    </iterate>
</isNotNull>
```

Con esta declaración me ha dado este error:

> 2019-09-24 09:58:52,378 ERROR [StackTrace] Full Stack Trace: 
>   com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: ParameterObject or property was not a Collection, Array or Iterator.

Me estoy volviendo un poco loco con ibatis... ¿Cómo le puedo pasar a la clausula where la lista de String?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Quizás llegué un poco tarde, yo lo que hubiese hecho es tomar la lista **listadoEESS** y con un método de Java la convertiría al string que voy a poner en la cláusula IN.
Por ejemplo si la lista hubiese sido algo como:

```
ArrayList<String> listadoEESS = new ArrayList<String>( Arrays. asList( "x" , "y" , "z" ) );
```

La hubiese llevado a un string igual a `('x','y','z')`. De esta manera lo podés usar tal como lo hiciste con los otros dos campos y te evitas la creación dinámica del Mapper porque ese **iterate** va a hacer que la query tenga que volver a crearse cada vez que quieras hacer una consulta.